# How can I get existing Azure resources inside subscription in Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm

I would like to know how to get the existing resources on subscription level in Terraform. As far as I understand, `azurerm_resources` provides them on a resource group basis.
In principle this is the same as in [How can I get active address space of tagged Azure VNets inside Terraform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62519071/how-can-i-get-active-address-space-of-tagged-azure-vnets-inside-terraform), but on *subscription* level.

EDIT:
I think it turns out to be a problem of using

```
type = Microsoft.Resources/ResourceGroups
```

that somehow does not seem to be a valid type for data sources. When I changed the type back to

```
type=Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks
```

the logic actually worked.

Comment: @4c74356b41 See my EDIT. What do you think about that?

Answer (score 1):

the same way:

```
terraform import resource_type_name.example resourceId
```

example from official docs:

```
terraform import azurerm_policy_assignment.assignment1  /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-000000000000/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/assignment1
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/policy_assignment.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not want to use terraform import, but rather have a data source in my main.tf. The idea is to get all reserved ip addresses of the current subscription. Do you know if there is an option for that as well?

Comment: yeah, you can use a data resource, but it wouldn't allow to get all the resources in the subscription, I'd think you need a separate data resource for each